# How to convert my lat and longs to UTM within my dataframe

Tags: r, geospatial, adehabitathr

I'm a bit stuck at the moment, i have been able to create a spatial points data frame and out of this i made an object of the class Ltraj. This i will need to do further analysis. But my x and y coordinates aren't in UTM which might give problems if i do further analysis down the line.

Format:

```
      x        y                date        dx         dy         dist   dt             
1 -32.09245 116.0426 2015-08-07 00:22:00 -2.19e-05  0.0000194 2.925696e-05 1800 ...
```

Structure:

```
List of 1
 $ :'data.frame':   109 obs. of  10 variables:
  ..$ x        : num [1:109] -32.1 -32.1 -32.1 -32.1 -32.1 ...
  ..$ y        : num [1:109] 116 116 116 116 116 ...
  ..$ date     : POSIXct[1:109], format: "2015-08-07 00:22:00" "2015-08-07   00:52:00" "2015-08-07 01:22:00" "2015-08-07 01:52:00" ...
  ..$ dx       : num [1:109] -2.19e-05 -5.73e-05 -5.15e-05 4.52e-05 -4.96e- 05 ...
  ..$ dy       : num [1:109] 1.94e-05 -3.21e-04 -2.61e-05 2.75e-04 -1.06e-04 ...
  ..$ dist     : num [1:109] 2.93e-05 3.26e-04 5.77e-05 2.79e-04 1.17e-04 ...
  ..$ dt       : num [1:109] 1800 1800 1800 3840 1800 3600 1740 1920 4680 900 ...
  ..$ R2n      : num [1:109] 0.00 8.56e-10 9.71e-08 1.24e-07 1.00e-08 ...
  ..$ abs.angle: num [1:109] 2.42 -1.75 -2.67 1.41 -2.01 ...
  ..$ rel.angle: num [1:109] NA 2.119 -0.925 -2.203 2.865 ...
  ..- attr(*, "id")= chr "2172"
  ..- attr(*, "burst")= chr "2172"
  ..- attr(*, "infolocs")='data.frame': 109 obs. of  1 variable:
  .. ..$ pkey: Factor w/ 109 levels "2172.2015-08-07 00:22:00",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 - attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "ltraj" "list"
 - attr(*, "typeII")= logi TRUE
 - attr(*, "regular")= logi FALSE
 - attr(*, "proj4string")=Formal class 'CRS' [package "sp"] with 1 slot
  .. ..@ projargs: chr NA
```

-->I was able to create a formal class Spatial points set from my lats and longs in the UTM format but that is a seperate object now:

Structure:

```
Formal class 'SpatialPoints' [package "sp"] with 3 slots
  ..@ coords     : num [1:109, 1:2] 409662 409664 409634 409631 409657 ...
  .. ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. .. ..$ : NULL
  .. .. ..$ : chr [1:2] "coords.x1" "coords.x2"
  ..@ bbox       : num [1:2, 1:2] 406647 13536726 415659 13551107
  .. ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. .. ..$ : chr [1:2] "coords.x1" "coords.x2"
  .. .. ..$ : chr [1:2] "min" "max"
  ..@ proj4string:Formal class 'CRS' [package "sp"] with 1 slot
  .. .. ..@ projargs: chr "+init=epsg:32750 +proj=utm +zone=50 +south    +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0"
```

I basically want my values for x and y in the ltraj to be in UTM,
I guess i will probably have to do this before i create the object ltraj or even the spatial points dataframe.

I was wondering if anybody has any advice as to change my lats and longs to UTM within the original dataframe; or to make it into a spatial dataframe and then bind them again with the dataframe that contains "subject" and "date"?

Kind regards,

Sam Rycken

Comment: The rgdal package can do this. See this [Previous Posting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33456934/lat-long-conversion-to-utm-loop-r-code)

Comment: Why is this labeled `python`?

Comment: see `?sp::spTransform`.